# Why the accept order not euqal connect order in socket?

Tags: c, sockets

First, I writing a server and a client thread refer from [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#a-simple-stream-server).

And I made some changes as follow:

**Server.c**

```
void *server(void *pdata){
...
printf("server ----> 1\n");
// wait for accept
printf("server ----> 2\n");
...
}
```

**Client.c**

```
void *client( void *pdata ){
...
printf("client ----->(%d) 1\n", gettid( ));
// wait for accept
printf("client ---->(%d) 1\n", gettid( ));
...
}
```

**main.c**

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    pthread_t serverid;
    pthread_t id;
    void *tmp;

    pthread_create( &serverid, NULL, server, NULL );

    sleep(1);
    pthread_create( &id, NULL, client, NULL );
    pthread_create( &id, NULL, client, NULL );

    pthread_join( serverid, &tmp );

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this test case, sometime I will get right order like this:

```
server ----> 1
client ----->(36317) 1
client ----->(36318) 1
client ----->(36317) 2
client ----->(36318) 2
server ----> 2
server ----> 1
server ----> 2
server ----> 1
```

But, in half of the time the result looks like this:

```
server ----> 1
client ----->(36347) 1
client ----->(36348) 1
client ----->(36348) 2
client ----->(36347) 2
server ----> 2
server ----> 1
server ----> 2
server ----> 1
```

**My question is why I can get the Non-strict order of TCP request.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to networking at all. Threads are not guaranteed to be started in the same order that you specify, so this is pretty much normal. Please read about threading and if possible about POSIX threads so that you can get a better insight.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your reminder, I do have a bug in this example